# How does rename() actually work under the hood in C?

Tags: c, file-io, rename

Does rename() make a copy of the file into another file and then delete the original one? Or is there some other way it works?

I couldn't find anything on the internet which explains this.

Comment: Note that `rename()` is a *system call*, so it greatly depends on the OS.

Comment: No, it’s not classic copy/swap that we do in C. File renaming only calls a system function/interrupt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact mechanisms depend entirely on the OS and file system in use, but in general a file's name is stored in a directory.  So typically changing the name of a file involves modifying the name in the directory listing (or if moving the file, removing the directory entry and adding it elsewhere in the tree).